MS Word 2019 - creating own Backstage View pane in ribbon.xml
In Word 2010 time I can created backstage view in ribbon.xml without any problems using something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691833(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Now I need to create something similar in Word 2019 and I can't.
Copilot sugesst me something like this:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <!-- Your existing tabs here -->
    </tabs>

    <backstage>
          <tab id="tab1" label="Info">
              <firstColumn>
                  <group id="group1" label="Info">
                      <labelControl id="lbl1" label="Version:"/>
                      <labelControl id="lbl2" label="Date:"/>
                      <labelControl id="lbl3" label="User:"/>
                  </group>
              </firstColumn>
          </tab>
      </backstage>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>

but .Invalidate method on ribbon object throw null refference exception (which error I always had when there were problem with ribbon.xml)
I see that in oldest version <backstage> tag is outside <ribbon> and newest is inside (or only Copilot suggest wrong), but I checked both with the same result.
How define backstage in MS Word 2019?

Your customUI XML has some invalid tags, and the ribbon and backstage tags need to be separated. I recommend you to use something like the Custom UI Editor when designing your ribbon. It has a validate function that will tell you exactly what is wrong in your XML-code and can be found here: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm
Try something like the following for your customUI XML:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
     <tabs>
        <tab id="tab1" label="Tab #1">
           <group id="grp1" label="Groupname" >
              <button id="btn1" label="Button" />
           </group>
        </tab>
     </tabs>
  </ribbon>
  <backstage>
     <tab id="customTab" label="Custom">
        <firstColumn>
           <taskGroup id="customTaskGroup" label="Custom Task Group">
              <category id="tgCategory1" label="Category One">
                 <task id="task1" label="Task 1" imageMso="FileOpen"/>
                 <task id="task2" label="Task 2" imageMso="FileSave"/>
                 <task id="task3" label="Task 3" imageMso="FileSaveAs"/>
              </category>
           </taskGroup>
        </firstColumn>
     </tab>
  </backstage>
</customUI>


You are absolutely right. Thank you very much. As a proof that I checked and works, I added closing tag  to your code. Thanks once again.

Nice catch! I would like to say that it was intentional, but nah. :)
